# Cucumber: How to write snippets/step definitions in PHP?

Tags: php, ruby, cucumber

I am trying to get Cucumber working to test a PHP application. So far I am able to get the feature to run by simplying running `cucumber` in my features directory. At the bottom of the results, it says:

> If you want snippets in a different programming language, just make sure a file
> with the appropriate file extension exists where cucumber looks for step definitions.

What does this mean exactly? I'm fine with writing most of my step definitions in Ruby, but at some point, I'm going to need to create some setup data (ideally creating it in PHP). How can I write step definitions in PHP as this statement suggests?

FYI: I am new to Ruby and Cucumber as well.

---

### Solution: [Cuke4PHP](https://github.com/olbrich/cuke4php)

Cuke4PHP implements the Cucumber wire protocol, making it possible to write step definitions in PHP.

Comment: how are you testing?  Simulated browser? Real Browser? What OS?

Comment: Not sure what is possible when testing a PHP application with Cucumber, but I was able to get Selenium working with webrat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't find a solution, this is what I found today! This guy spared me the work I had to do to use PHP lol

https://github.com/olbrich/cuke4php

He has implemented the [wire protocol](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Wire-Protocol) for PHP. This in a nutshell is another server that runs PHP steps when Cucumber finds any. Also passes back the results.

Ah no need to configure env.rb any more.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Behat, a PHP version of Cucumber: http://everzet.com/Behat/

Comment: Behat looks nice, but it also requires PHP 5.3 which is sort of a deal breaker for me right now.

Answer (score 2):

Step definitions are stored in `features/step_definitions` and are what tells Cucumber what to do when it encounters statements like "Given I have 3 cucumbers in my belly":

```
Given /^I have (\d+) cucumbers in my belly$/ do |cukes|
  # Some Ruby code here
end
```

http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Step-Definitions

To write your steps in PHP, just put them in `features/step_definitions` and configure your environment (`features/support/env.rb`) accordingly. There's good information in the form of a Cucumber feature for this in the Cucumber docs:

http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/php

A quick Google search also brought up the following article on PHP testing with Cucumber, Webrat and Selenium which looks pretty useful:

http://dev.af83.com/testing/acceptance-tests-php-project-cucumber-webrat-selenium-trio/2010/06/03

Other languages that are not directly supported can use Cucumber's wire protocol, which is e.g. what Clucumber (Common Lisp) does:

http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/wire-protocol

I don't do PHP, but I hope my answer still helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already read those articles. The PHP wiki page doesn't talk about how to set up the `support/env.rb` to be able to write step definitions in PHP which is what I am trying to figure out how to do. I haven't been able to find any information on how to write a step definition in a language other than Ruby. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: The PHP wiki page has an example `environment.rb`, right afer 'And I put the following in "features/support/env.rb"'. Maybe look at Behat, it's a port of Cucumber's language (Gherkin) to PHP: http://everzet.com/Behat/

Comment: Thanks for the link to Behat. Wasn't aware of a PHP fork of Cucumber. Just wish it didn't require PHP 5.3 to run. =/